# Node CLI commands through kubectl exec pod_name --

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, kubectl, rethinkdb, reql

I am trying to build a script, which would be running database queries on a pod, after loading node CLI. Manually, i run kubectl exec pod_name -- node test.js, and that would give me a CLI and I run my queries there. Is there a way I can add this step in an automation bash script?

Thanks!

I tried,

```
kubectl exec -it rethinkdb-pod -- node test.js; r.dbList()
kubectl exec -it rethinkdb-pod -- node test.js && r.dbList()
kubectl exec -it rethinkdb-pod -- node "test.js; r.dbList()"
```

I also tried to create a script and pass it on to the exec, but no luck there!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to run `test.js` but also evaluate arbitrary JS **within the context of `test.js`**?

Comment: Just remove the interactive flag

Comment: @Hackerman: the interactive mode is used to view the output then and there, removing interactive flag didn't work for what I am expecting

Comment: @DaveNewton: the test.json sets up databse environment for me. So the ultimate question is, how can run a command in node CLI from kubectl exec window? I can run commands A, B and C as **kubectl exec pod_name -- A && B && C** , if it was bash, but here when i run **kubectl exec pod_name -- node**, it open a CLI for me, and I need to run command D, E and F on the CLI, so is it possible that I pass the commands D, E and F as ** kubectl exec pod_name -- node; D; E;F ** ?

Comment: Short answer is, you can run multiple commands. But it seems that you already know the answer

Comment: @Hackerman: I do, but not quite exactly I wanna do. Running **exec** opens up a bash/sh shell for me, but this is node shell I am dealing with, and I was kinda hoping to find an asnwer for that.

Comment: Why can’t you write a script instead of trying to run a JS file and try to pass code to it?

Comment: @DaveNewton Because this is a onetime thing, and I dont want to invest my time in building a script. I would have to go with writing the script, if I am left with no alterntatives.

Comment: “Building a script” means appending the JS you want to run to the script you’re already running. I mean… it’s already been two hours; a little late to be thinking about saving time.